# golang: channel in select statement is only receiving sometimes (???)

Tags: select, go, channel

I have a select statement in a go routine that receives from two channels.

```
for {
    fmt.Printf("Waiting for select statement ...\n")
    select {
    case req := <-requestChan:
        fmt.Printf("I got a request: %v\n", req)
    case <-doneChan:
        fmt.Printf("serveDatabase: Got closing signal. Stop serving.\n")
        return
    }
}
```

If the calling function sends to first channel twice and then to second channel everything works fine:

```
requestChan <- Db_request{ request: "Login", beehive: "yaylaswiese" }
requestChan <- Db_request{ request: "Signup", beehive: "aziz nezir" }

fmt.Printf("Sending true to the doneChannel\n")
doneChan <- true
```

The console output (correctly) is:

```
>     Waiting for select statement ...
>     I got a request: {Login yaylaswiese}
>     Waiting for select statement ...
>     Sending true to the doneChannel
>     I got a request: {Signup aziz nezir}
>     Waiting for select statement ...
>     serveDatabase: Got closing signal. Stop serving.
```

However, if I comment the second request like

```
requestChan <- Db_request{ request: "Login", beehive: "yaylaswiese" }
// requestChan <- Db_request{ request: "Signup", beehive: "aziz nezir" }

fmt.Printf("Sending true to the doneChannel\n")
doneChan <- true
```

Then the output is

```
>     Waiting for select statement ...
>     I got a request: {Login yaylaswiese}
>     Waiting for select statement ...
>     Sending true to the doneChannel
```

So the doneChan is never received. I tried also to go into a endless loop after sending doneChan, but it has the same result.

What could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, your `main` is exiting before the other goroutine finalised. Note that they're concurrent, and once `main` finishes, all other goroutines are killed.

You need to explicitly synchronize the end of your goroutines with `main`. [You can use sync.WaitGroup for that](http://play.golang.org/p/q7MWWx_9fp), or another channel.

Comment: In addition, take into account that if both requestChan and doneChan have data, select may pick doneChan first, and the for loop will exit before all data is read from requestChan.

Comment: By the way, providing a valid example of your problem in the Go Playground helps focusing the discussion and is appreciated by answerers. :)